# Can I get the full path to the file in PhpStorm Code Templates?

Tags: phpstorm, velocity, code-templates

When I create a Code Template in PhpStorm, is there a way in the template (or in an include) to get the full path to the file that is about to be created?

For example, I know you can use `${FILE_NAME}` to get the name of the file, but is there also something like `${PATH}` or something? Or can I do something like this myself?

Comment: AFAIK -- no. What exactly you need this for?

Answer (score 1):

There are no predefined template variables for file path, please vote for [IDEA-136387](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-136387) to be notified on any progress with this feature.